# jQuery broken animation - Div doesnt disappear sometimes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Last days I've been attempting to make a sidebar with jQuery animation, but something probably went wrong and it seems to be kinda broken and not fully working, as the #navigation (div) sometimes doesnt even disappear, it probably depends on the place where I get my mouse out of the div as it disappears only on some of the places.
And another thing/problem I found in the code result is that when you hit the left corner many times repeatedly, then the #navigation keeps appearing and disappearing over and over again, as much times as I've hit the corner.
How can I fix these little, but provoking problems?

Here is the code I've written today:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="hidden">
        <h3>Navigation</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Live</a>
        <a href="#">Events</a>
        <a href="#">Genres</a>
        <a href="#">The team</a>
        <a href="#">Changelog</a>

        <div class="userpanel">
            <a href="#">Sign in</a>
            <a href="#">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#navigation").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: '300px',
        opacity: '1',
    }, 400);
    $("#hidden").css({
        display: 'block',
    });
});

$("#navigation").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: '5px',
        opacity: '0.0',
    }, 400);
    $("#hidden").css({
        display: 'none',
    });
});
</script>
```

And well... Here is the CSS:

```
#navigation {width: 5px; height: calc(100vh - 50px); background: #171C21; opacity: 0.0; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
#navigation #hidden {width: 90%; margin: auto; height: 100%; display: none; text-align: center;}
#navigation #hidden > h3 {color: #FFFFFF; text-transform: uppercase;}
#navigation #hidden a {width: 200px; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px; margin: auto;}
#navigation #hidden a:hover {color: #8e44ad;}
#navigation .userpanel > a {font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600;}
```

And I'm using this version of jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7rc2.js"></script>
```

Preview: http://awesomeness.adam.zur.io/ (hit left side of the screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you didn't intend to stop current animation using **[.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** as it will glitch when mouse-enter/leaves and cache it. as you should change mousemove to mouseenter, as it will only fire event once.

```
$("#navigation").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '300px',
        opacity: '1',
    }, 400);
    $("#hidden").css({
        display: 'block',
    });
});

$("#navigation").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '5px',
        opacity: '0.0',
    }, 400);
    $("#hidden").css({
        display: 'none',
    });
});
```

[working code](http://goo.gl/nlDvmK)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code ( See this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrNEEO)** ) just add class `is-showing` and style it with css, and with jquery when you hover the navigation add this class to `navigation`

```
#navigation {
  width: 300px; 
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); 
  background: #171C21; 
  padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity:0
}
#navigation.is-showing{
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}
```

js:

```
$('#navigation').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is-showing')
})
```